# SharePoint 2010 Enable Enterprise features

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We enabled Enterprise features on our SharePoint 2010 farm by following this [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261946(v=office.14).aspx) article. Everything seemed to have worked, however, the datasource list template seems to be giving errors everytime we try create a list based from this template.

Edit: This is the error I get [image]

Edit 2: This is the list type being used [image]

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: whoops sorry :-) I was excited.  It says SharePoint Foundation version 3 templates are not supported. Here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/4u6ibo

Comment: Do you think it is possible for you to add that image to your post (there is functionality for appending images directly to the post body)? :)

Comment: sorry, embedded in post :)

Comment: is that a custom template or appear after enabling EE?

Comment: as far as I know it isnt a custom template, and apparently it started happening after enabling EE.  I have googled loads and this error does point to a custom template after an upgrade of a version.  But there was no version change only enable Enterprise features.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to original post above indicating the offending template.

Comment: @Chunkyfeather - What is the description for the list? Even if it seems strange, it does almost seem that this is a custom template..

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry, it is a custom template, its resolved now by downloading the offending stp file, updating the manifest from version 3 to 4. These steps were taken to resolve. http://pradeephegde.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/moving-a-list-template-from-moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010/  I never even considered it being a custom template.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: That was the idea I was going to post next

Answer (score 2):

Issue closed, resolved by editing the offending list template as stated above.

The template was a custom template originally created for SharePoint 2007.
I downloaded the stp file, updated the manifest version from 3 to 4, rebuilt the file and reuploaded it. Now the template works correctly.

For further details, have a look [here](http://pradeephegde.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/moving-a-list-template-from-moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010/);